# Looking for Google Apps script to find and highlight dates from past month in red

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I have a Google spreadsheet with columns I and J with data as headers Est Closing Month and Est Closing Calendar Year respectively, I need a script which will loop through columns I and J and find dates which are in the past month of this year and highlight them in Red.

Following is example data
ColI ColJ
Aug 2014
Nov 2014
Aug 2014
Jul 2014
Jul 2014
Dec 2014
Dec 2014

After I run the script the output put should be 
Aug 2014
Nov 2014
Aug 2014
Jul 2014 -> Both Cells should be in red
Jul 2014 -> Both Cells should be in red
Dec 2014
Dec 2014

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried conditional formatting ?

[image]

Comment: If the date format is in mm/dd/yyyy format I could have done that. The values are in two different fields, Column i has month ex: Aug and column J has year 2014.

Comment: couldn't you combine both columns in a third one that would be a full date ? Even in a script it would be (a bit) cumbersome if the info are strings instead of dates...(are these strings or dates shown as "month only" ? you can test it by double clicking on it : if it shows a popup with a calendar then it's a date, else it's a string.)

Comment: I was able to get through the following script which gives me the output of a complete date

Comment: function onOpen() {
  var sourceRangeName = 'Form Responses 1!J2:K800';
  var destRangeName = 'Form Responses 1!L2';
  var names = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(sourceRangeName).getValues(); var fullNames = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    fullNames.push([names[i][0] + ' ' + names[i][1]]);
  }
var destRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(destRangeName).offset(0, 0, fullNames.length); 
  destRange.setValues(fullNames);}

Comment: Now I need the program to loop through the new date column and highlight cells in red which come from previous month instead of conditional formatting each time